# PDF Entropy calculation

Tags: pdf, encryption, hex, metadata, entropy

Last time mkl helped me a lot, hopefully he (or someone else) can help me with these questions too. Unfortunately I couldn't get access to the ISO norm (ISO 32000-1 or 32000-2).

1. Are these bytes used for padding? I have tried several files, and they all have padding characters. This is quite remarkable, as I would expect that this substantial amount of low entropy bytes should significantly lower the average entropy of the PDF file. However, this does not seem to be the case, as the average entropy of a PDF file is almost eight bits)

[image]

2. Furthermore, this (meta)data should be part of an object stream, and therefore compressed, but this is not the case (Is there a specific reason for this)..?) (magenta = high entropy/random, how darker the color, how lower the entropy, In generated this image with http://binvis.io/#/)

[image]

3. These are the entropy values ​​of a .doc file (**not **docx), that I converted to a PDF with version 1.4, as this version should not contain object streams etc. However, the entropy values ​​of this file are still quite high. I would think that the entropy of a PDF with version <1.5 would have a lower entropy value on average, as it does not use object streams, but the results are similar to a PDF with version 1.5

[image]

I hope somebody can help me with these questions. Thank you.

**Added part:**

The trailer dictionary has a variable length, and with PDF 1.5 (or higher) it can be part of the central directory stream, not only the length but also the position/offset of the trailer dictionary can vary (although is it.. because it seems that even if the trailer dictionary is part of the central directory stream, it is always at the end of the file?, at least... in all the PDFs I tested). The only thing I don't really understand is that for some reason the researchers of [this study](https://rdcu.be/c0XU7) assumed that the trailer has a *fixed size* and a fixed position (the last 164 bytes of a file).

They also mention in Figure 8 that a PDF file encrypted by EasyCrypt, has some structure in both the header and the trailer (which is why it has a lower entropy value compared to a PDF file encrypted with ransomware).

However, when I encrypt a file with EasyCrypt (I tried three different symmetric encryption algorithms: AES 128 bit, AES 256 bit and RC2) and encrypt several PDF files (with different versions), I get a fully encrypted file, without any structure/metadata that is not encrypted (neither in the header nor in the trailer). However, when I encrypt a file with Adobe Acrobat Pro, the structure of the PDF file is preserved. This makes sense, since the PDF extension has its own standardised format for encrypting files, but I don't really understand why they mention that EasyCrypt conforms to this standardised format.

PDF Header encrypted with EasyCrypt:
[image]

PDF Header encrypted with Adobe Acrobat Pro:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately I couldn't get access to the ISO norm (ISO 32000-1 or 32000-2).

https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/PDF32000_2008.pdf

> 1. Are these bytes used for padding?

Those bytes are part of a metadata stream. The format of the metadata is XMP. According to the XMP spec:

> ***Padding**  It is recommended that applications allocate 2 KB to 4 KB of padding to the packet. This allows the XMP to be edited in place, and expanded if necessary, without overwriting existing application data. The padding must be XML-compatible whitespace; the recommended practice is to use the space character (U+0020) in the appropriate encoding, with a newline about every 100 characters.*

So yes, *these bytes are used for padding*.

> 2. Furthermore, this (meta)data should be part of an object stream, and therefore compressed, but this is not the case (Is there a specific reason for this)..?)

Indeed, there is. The pdf document-wide metadata streams are intended to be readable by applications, too, that don't know the PDF format but do know the XMP format. Thus, these streams should not be compressed or encrypted.

> 3. ...

I don't see a question in that item.

> Added part

> the position/offset of the trailer dictionary can vary (although is it.. because it seems that even if the trailer dictionary is part of the central directory stream, it is always at the end of the file?, at least... in all the PDFs I tested)

Well, as the stream in question contains cross reference information for the objects in the PDF, it usually is only finished pretty late in the process of creating the PDF an, therefore, added pretty late to the PDF file. Thus, an end-ish position of it usually is to be expected.

> The only thing I don't really understand is that for some reason the researchers of [this study](https://link.springer.com/epdf/10.1007/s00500-018-3257-z?sharing_token=HbEh6lZtBMjaCFnku-QEe_e4RwlQNchNByi7wbcMAY5TLD32SlN7cEh_fLCiGNkHlMB_RSH84UHojcPgeG97aOkTEphA_ecVVlm-xNa7EY5wsq1ox1N-HoSjiNBhlCHFzQMr0EKZgA7a-2oZkYGT2ypHncl5DkqAUCGIF_FYxsM%3D) assumed that the trailer has a *fixed size* and a fixed position (the last 164 bytes of a file).

As already discussed, assuming a fixed position or length of the trailer in general is wrong.

If you wonder why they assumed such a fixed size nonetheless, you should ask them.

If I were to *guess* why they did, I'd assume that their set of 200 PDFs simply was not generic. In the paper they don't mention how they selected those PDFs, so maybe they used a batch they had at their hands without checking how special or how generic it was. If those files were generated by the same PDF creator, chances indeed are that the trailers have a constant (or near constant) length.

If this assumption is correct, i.e. if they worked with a not-generic set of test files only, then their results, in particular their entropy values and confidence intervals and the concluded quality of the approach, are questionable.

> They also mention in Figure 8 that a PDF file encrypted by EasyCrypt, has some structure in both the header and the trailer (which is why it has a lower entropy value compared to a PDF file encrypted with ransomware).

> However, when I encrypt a file with EasyCrypt (I tried three different symmetric encryption algorithms: AES 128 bit, AES 256 bit and RC2) and encrypt several PDF files (with different versions), I get a fully encrypted file, without any structure/metadata that is not encrypted (neither in the header nor in the trailer).

In the paper they show a hex dump of their file encrypted by EasyCrypt:

[image: Screenshot from paper]

Here there is some metadata (albeit not PDF specific) that should show less entropy.

As your EasyCrypt encryption results differ, there appear to be different modes of using EasyCrypt, some of which add this header and some don't. Or maybe EasyCrypt used to add such headers but doesn't anymore.

Either way, this again indicates that the research behind the paper is not generic enough, taking just the output of one encryption tool in one mode (or in one version) as representative example for data encrypted by non-ransomware.

Thus, the results of the article are of very questionable quality.

> the PDF extension has its own standardised format for encrypting files, but I don't really understand why they mention that EasyCrypt conforms to this standardised format.

If I haven't missed anything, they merely mention that *A constant regularity exists in the header portion of the normally encrypted files*, they don't say that this *constant regularity* does *conform to this standardised format*.

Comment: Hi mkl, thank you for your answer and for the link. My third question was (please consider the last image): 
"These are the entropy values ​​of a .doc file (**not **docx), that I converted to a PDF with version 1.4, as this version should not contain object streams etc. However, the entropy values ​​of this file are still quite high. I would think that the entropy of a PDF with version <1.5 would have a lower entropy value on average, as it does not use object streams, but the results are similar to a PDF with version 1.5."

Comment: Well, even without object streams there usually are a lot compressed streams in the file. If encryption is used, even data outside of compressed streams add a lot of entropy. Also you talk about your experiences with a single specific file which might be special. For details, therefore, please share that pdf.

Comment: Hi mkl, the link you shared is very useful. I have added a question in my opening post, could you take a look at it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @mkl Could you please take a look at this question (the added part). Thank you sir.

Comment: @Moooz I have already had a look, see the edit of my answer, starting at "Added part"...

Comment: @mkl Thanks for the detailed reply, and..
"If you wonder why they assumed such a fixed size nonetheless, you should ask them". I have emailed the authors three times (in October, November and the last one a few days ago), but they have not responded. I think your assumption makes sense, their dataset of only 200 PDF files is (probably) not representative of "the real world'